# How to rid out white background in front of camera in three.js?

Tags: three.js

Using three.js library, I have created a simple cube background and loading the models inside that.

When I visualize the canvas, I am getting background color in front of the camera. In the below screenshot, I want to rid out of the rectangle area.

The application is hosted here.

[Hosted Link](http://creative-labs.in/test/)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnD0N.png)

The code goes here.

```js
 var WIDTH, HEIGHT, selectionBox, camera, scene, projector, container;


 WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
 HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

 container = document.getElementById("container");

 scene = new THREE.Scene();

 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, 1000);

 scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(500, 10));

 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
   alpha: true,
   antialias: true,
   preserveDrawingBuffer: true
 });

 renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
 //renderer.setClearColor(0xff0000);

 container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

 window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

 controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
 controls.target.z = 150;

 render();

 cubemap("Cloud");

 function onWindowResize() {

   camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
   camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

   renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
 }


 function render() {
   var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
     window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
   window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
   requestAnimationFrame(render);
   controls.update();
   renderer.render(scene, camera);
 };

 function cubemap(imagename) {

   var urls = [
     imagename + "-BACK.jpg",
     imagename + "-FRONT.jpg",
     imagename + "-TOP.jpg",
     imagename + "-BOTTOM.jpg",
     imagename + "-RIGHT.jpg",
     imagename + "-LEFT.jpg"
   ];
   var cubemap;
   cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls);
   cubemap.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

   var shader = THREE.ShaderLib["cube"];
   shader.uniforms["tCube"].value = cubemap;

   var skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
     fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
     vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
     uniforms: shader.uniforms,
     depthWrite: false,
     side: THREE.BackSide
   });

   var skybox = new THREE.Mesh(
     new THREE.CubeGeometry(2000, 2000, 2000),
     skyBoxMaterial
   );
   skybox.position.set(0, -50, 0);
   skybox.name = "ROOFTOP";
   //skybox.scale.set(30, 30, 30);
   scene.add(skybox);
 };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/a72347515fa34e892f7a9bfa66a34fdc0df55954/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>


<div id="container">

</div>
```

Can anyone help me to fix the issue. It should show the background image.

Appreciate your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing the background because the camera settings is clipping at 1000 units.

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, 1000);
```

The above line is clipping the view anything below 0.1 and above 1000 units, so either you reduce the cube size to below 1000 or increase the 1000 in camera to value greater than 2000.

Answer (score 0):

```
var skybox = new THREE.Mesh(
     new THREE.CubeGeometry(2000, 2000, 2000),
     skyBoxMaterial
   );
```

I change to

```
 var skybox = new THREE.Mesh(
     new THREE.CubeGeometry(800, 800, 800),
     skyBoxMaterial
   );
```

And it disappear.

Comment: When we reduce the cube geometry size, it is getting disappear. But when you zoom-out the same problem occurs. Also, I need a big cube geometry  (big environment) of about 1500 to 2000.